# .Net Database Querying Options Aside Linq

Tags: .net, database

I've been doing a lot of implementation in Linq recently, and it suddenly occurred to me that as great as it is, I haven't really explored any other options.

Any thoughts?

Comment: The other options suck compared to linq :P

Comment: Some of the answers suggest that your question should be more precise. I assume you equate LINQ with LINQ to SQL. But there is also LINQ to Entities etc. 
Are you looking for an ORM?

Comment: Yes i meant Linq to Sql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the other answers:

- [Codesmith Templates](http://www.codesmithtools.com/),
- the [Enterprise Library (4.0)](http://www.codeplex.com/entlib) (specifically, the Data Access Block)..
- Stored Procedures with ADO..
- [Deklarit](http://www.deklarit.com/)
- [NetTiers](http://nettiers.com/)

Answer (score 4):

Well, SQL is a perfectly fine alternative.

However, I think you may be looking for something like the [ADO.NET Entity Framework](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/ado-net-entity.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [SubSonic](http://subsonicproject.com/)?

It does linq, code generation, and some fluid queries.

Answer (score 0):

[Subsonic](http://subsonicproject.com/), [NHibernate](https://www.hibernate.org/343.html) (don't forget to look at [Fluent NHibernate](http://fluentnhibernate.org/)), [Typed DataSets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/esbykkzb(VS.71).aspx) (yuck), [MS Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa697427(VS.80).aspx) and [iBatis](http://ibatis.apache.org/dotnetdownloads.cgi) all come to mind.

Answer (score 0):

[NHibernate](https://www.hibernate.org/343.html) is another good ORM. Or [EntityFramework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa697427(VS.80).aspx)